# I want to save multiple data in my file system

Tags: java

`

```
    NumberFormat currency = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);


    String employeeName;    
    float hoursWorked;          
    float hourlyRate;           
    float basepay;          
    float netpay;
    float overtime = 0;
    int numberofemp= 0;
    final JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        System.out.println( "Assignement 2\n\n");   
            numberofemp = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter No of Employee"));

     int[] arrayList= new int[numberofemp];
       for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.length; i++)

      {
             employeeName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the employee name:");

       do
        {
           hourlyRate = Float.parseFloat(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the number of Hourly Rate :"));

           if (hourlyRate < 8)
                {   
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(panel, "The hourly rate must be 8 an hour", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
              }
       while ( hourlyRate < 8 ); 

           do
             {
               hoursWorked = Float.parseFloat(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the number of hours worked:"));

            if (hoursWorked >60)
            {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(panel, "The number of hours worked must be under 60", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);                     
            }
          }
        while ( hoursWorked >60);


                    if (hoursWorked > 40)
                        {
                        overtime = (float) (  (hoursWorked - 40) *(hourlyRate * 1.5));
                        }

                        else
                        { basepay = hoursWorked * hourlyRate;

                        }
        netpay  =  basepay + overtime;          

        System.out.println( "\n\nEmployee Name: " + employeeName);      
         System.out.println( "Hours Worked: " + hoursWorked );
         System.out.println( "Base Pay: " + currency.format(basepay) );
          System.out.println( "Overtime Pay: " + currency.format(overtime)); 
           System.out.println( "Total Pay: " + currency.format(netpay)); 
            System.out.println( );


 try
  {
     PrintWriter prst;
         prst = new PrintWriter( "C://Users/tushar/Desktop/Workspace/Assignment_2/out.txt" );
              prst.println( "\n\nEmployee Name: " + employeeName);
                prst.println( "\n\nBasePay: " + basepay);
                  prst.println( "\n\nOvertime Pay: " + overtime);
                    prst.println( "\n\nTotal pay: " + netpay);
                       prst.close();

                                     }
 catch (Exception e)
 {
         System.err.println ("Error writing to file");
 }                      



       }
     }  }
```

Hi i got a little problem with my code. In my code i can only save last list of data.And In my file system i want to save multiple data.So any one could help me how can i save as many data as i like into my file system.

Comment: Wrap your `PrintWriter` in a [`FileOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream(java.io.File,%20boolean)) which has been constructed to append data (`FileOutputStream(File, boolean)`)

Answer (score 0):

take your PrintWriter initialization outside the for loop, and the close method to close the PrintWriter outside of the end of the for loop, if you want to use the file again and append to it so that the old data is not erased, us FileOutputStream(prst, true), as MadProgrammer suggested.

```
   PrintWriter prst = new PrintWriter( "C://Users/tushar/Desktop/Workspace/Assignment_2/out.txt" );
   int[] arrayList= new int[numberofemp];
   for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.length; i++)
   {
     ........................
     try
     {
      prst.println( "\n\nEmployee Name: " + employeeName);
      prst.println( "\n\nBasePay: " + basepay);
      prst.println( "\n\nOvertime Pay: " + overtime);
      prst.println( "\n\nTotal pay: " + netpay);

     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
       System.err.println ("Error writing to file");
     }                      
  }
  prst.close();
```